# Return response and execute some method (Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there an option for tomcat to return some response to a request whilst at the same time executing a method in a backend service?

In my use case, I have a query which takes ~60s to execute. I'd like to respond a string to the request to let the user know that it will take some time whilst still executing the query itself in the backend service.

So instead of something like this:

```
...
response = this.service.getSomeData(request);
return response;
```

I'd like to do this:

```
...
return "Data not found"
this.service.getSomeData(request); // actually stores the result in a s3 bucket
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute it using another thread:

```
class MyServiceExecution implements Runnable{  
public void run(){  
System.out.println("thread is running...");  
}  
  
public static void main(String args[]){  
MyServiceExecution m1=new MyServiceExecution();  
Thread t1 =new Thread(m1);  
t1.start();  
 }  
}
```

Be careful when you implement threads... Read some about performance, garbage collection, etc.

Comment: This does not cover nearly enough detail to even begin to be helpful. Background processing of requests at the very least requires mention on Servlet 3.1 async and ideally requires a discussion of other options - that likely fit the OPs use case better. e.g starting the processing in the background and returning HTTP202 and allowing polling for a result.